# Cloudflare HTTPS error

Tags: ssl, hosting

I have my own hosting site, and I took SSL certificate from Godaddy. All setting done, and SSL is also working, now when I activate Cloudflare and open site, it shows SSL content error and so on. Why this error is happening?

Here is my site, I deactivated my Cloudflare right now, it's running now but with Cloudflare it's not running.

Is there any setting for Cloudflare?

Comment: Please post the mentioned errors.

Comment: Sir the error is coming like that.     SSL Content error

Answer (score 0):

On the support page of CloudFlare [the following article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170516-How-do-I-add-SSL-to-my-site-) can be found about adding SSL to you to your webpage.

If that fails I suggest that you contact CloudFlare support, as they will probably be able to help you the best.